# Why does my ASP.NET FormView always render EmptyTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource, formview

I've got an FormView bound to an ObjectDataSource placed inside an usercontrol, initialized with the following code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCampaign" runat="server"
    DataObjectTypeName="code.model.Campaign"
    TypeName="code.model.Campaign"
    SelectMethod="LoadCampaign">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="code" QueryStringField="id" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<%-- ... --%>

<asp:FormView ID="fvCampaign" runat="server"
    DataSourceID="odsCampaign">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <span>No campaign loaded.</span>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span>Campaign</span>
        <span><%# Eval("Subject") %></span>

        <%-- ... --%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

My code behind looks something like this:

```
// CampaignCallCollection inherits from IEnumerable<CampaignCall>
public class Campaign : CampaignCallCollection
{
    // Some property to show
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Campaign(int code)
        : base()
    {
        // Initialize the object based on the primary key passed to the constructor
        InitializeCampaign(code);
    }

    private void InitializeCampaign(int code)
    {
        // Initialization Code
    }

    // Loading method for ObjectDataSource
    public static Campaign LoadCampaign(int code)
    {
        // Return new instance of an initialized campaign object.
        Campaign oCampaign = new Campaign(code);
        //throw new Exception(oCampaign.Subject);
        return oCampaign;
    }
}
```

However if I enable the exception the proper subject text is passed as exception message. But my FormView does allways render the EmptyTemplate. I do not really see mistake in here. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it because it is expecting a list of Campaigns not an individual Campaign?

Comment: A Campaign in this case is defined as a list of CampaignCalls. The Campaign-Object itself describes some kind of meta-information for those calls. In my FormView I want to show those informations for a single campaign instance. This is why DataObjectTypeName is code.model.Campaign. But the idea is not bad - maybe a FormView is not able to render objects that directly or indirectly inherit from IEnumerable<>? I'll check this! :-)

Comment: Okay,

removing IEnumerable<> from the inheritence hierarchy fixed the problem. After some coding I have changed the relation between Campaign and CampaignCallCollection, so that Campaign does not inherit from CampaignCallCollection but holds an reference of an instance of this object.

Thank you very much :-)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Good news glad you sorted it out :D